# Why does this return after the first exec statement?

Tags: git, bash, shell

I have the following code

```
echo 000
exec sudo -u ubuntu -i git --git-dir=/home/ubuntu/Avails/.git --work-tree=/home/ubuntu/Avails/ fetch origin
echo 111
exec sudo -u ubuntu -i git --git-dir=/home/ubuntu/Avails/.git --work-tree=/home/ubuntu/Avails/ merge origin/production
echo 222
exec sudo bash -c "STAGE=production $DIR/transporter_pulldown.py"
echo 333
```

It only prints the `000` and then returns. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `help exec` it shows:

```
Replace the shell with the given command.
```

Because of this reason your first `echo` prints `000` and very next `sudo` replaces your shell and thus anything after `sudo` doesn't even run since shell is gone (it has been replaced by `sudo` command).

You probably don't want to have `exec` in your script and run it as:

```
echo '000'
sudo -u ubuntu -i git --git-dir=/home/ubuntu/Avails/.git --work-tree=/home/ubuntu/Avails/ fetch origin
echo '111'
sudo -u ubuntu -i git --git-dir=/home/ubuntu/Avails/.git --work-tree=/home/ubuntu/Avails/ merge origin/production
echo '222'
sudo bash -c "STAGE=production $DIR/transporter_pulldown.py"
echo '333'
```